# cname redirect causing phishing warning in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I changed my CNAME Records as outlined in this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains. The redirect itself works, the issue is in Chrome (and I assume other browsers) It gives me a phishing alert.

> This is probably not the site you are looking for!
>
> You attempted to reach app.grewpr.com, but instead you actually reached a server   i  identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of app.grewpr.com.
>
> You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

How would I fix this error? It also puts a red line through the https lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using HTTPS, you should follow slightly different DNS configuration instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#configuredns

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Is there a way to do this without buying the site endpoint addon? If not can I disable SSL?

Comment: If you want to use SSL on Heroku you either need to use a `*.herokuapp.com` domain, or use the site endpoint addon. SSL is the security layer in HTTPS; you can disable SSL if you use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: If I try to go to http://pure-chamber-1979.herokuapp.com/ or http://pure-chamber-1979.heroku.com/ it redirects me to http://pure-chamber-1979.herokuapp.com/ which has ssl. How would I make heroku stop doing this?

Comment: It looks to me like the redirect is coming from inside your app, not from Heroku (the redirect comes from WEBrick, and has an `X-Rack-Cache` header)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Your custom domain app uses your host certificate. Whether buy SSL addon or if 'http' is ok for you then change ssl settings for your app. In "environments/production.rb" there must be following configuration "**config.force_ssl = false**" which by default is set to true. Had to reset Firefox to take effect. Other browsers were ok.